# How to make an image flash/zoom full screen, which is present in a web page

Tags: javascript, html

I started working on advanced java few days before(too late to start on that, I know). I am stuck with a specific task of making an image (which is present on the body of the html page) throw or flash it or zoom it in full screen.

I have been searching for a while now but is there a way to make an image if click on then it would get bigger on users screen once then go back to normal.

Comment: Is [Lightbox](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) an option?